# "when 1 users approve your edit" contains a pluralization bug

Tags: bug, documentation, plurals

When it says "...will be visible when 1 user**s** approve your edit", it has an extra "S".

Considering how often this appears, I think this is worth fixing.

Side note: it should be "one" instead of "1". I learned it the hard way in english class...

<sup><sub>Please don't personally come to my house and knock me out with a giant "S" (reference to [this](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105))</sub></sup>

Comment: "...will be visible when ones user approves your edit"

Comment: 1 is 1, users is user(s)

Comment: /me changes handle to "1 users"

Comment: @JoshCaswell huh?

Comment: _it should be "one" instead of "1". I learned it the hard way in english class_ What does it matter whether it's 1 or one? It means the same thing.

Comment: Yes, in formal English writing, you always spell out numbers instead of using numerals. That's what you learned in English class. However, this is not formal writing, so using the numeral is perfectly acceptable. (Incorrect plurals are never okay.)

Comment: @Jojodmo: Won't work with localization.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have a delivery of a giant S coming soon

Comment: Apparently you didn't learn in your English class that "English" should be capitalized.

Comment: @wythagoras It's the internet. Pluralization bugs are not okay, capitalization is whatever